# Oracle DB vs Mariadb

Tags: mariadb

I have to find out in MariaDb how to implement some features used in Oracle . I have :

- Load a file: in Oracle I use the external table. Is there a way (fast and efficient one ) to load a file into a table . Has MariaDb a plugin which allows to load well a specific format of files?
- In my existing Oracle code I used to developp a java wrap functions which allow those feature (is there a way in MariaDb to do this?), specifically :

1- Searching a files in an OS directory and insert them in a table, 
2- send an SNMP trap 
3- Send a mail via SMTP

- Is there an equivalent to an Oracle job in Mariadb?
- Is there an equivalent to  Oracle TDE (Transparent data encryption) ?
- Is there an equivalent to  the VPD (virtual private policy)?
- What is the maximum length of a varchar column/variable ? (in Oracle we can use the CLOBs..)
  Many Thanks and Best Regards

Comment: You might want to do more research in the features of MariaDB so that you can ask a much more specific question. This is rather broad.

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB (and MySQL) can do a `LOAD DATA` on a CSV file.  It is probably the most efficient way to convert external data to a table.  (There is also `ENGINE=CSV`, which requires no conversion, but is limited in that it has no indexes, etc.)

MariaDB *cannot*, for security reasons, issue any arbitrary system calls.  No emails, no 'exec', etc.

No Job, TDE, VPD.

Network transmissions can (optionally) use SSL for encryption at that level.

There is a family of virtually identical datatypes for characters:

```
CHAR(n), VARCHAR(n) -- where n is up to 65535; n is the limit of _characters_, not _bytes_.
TINYTEXT, TEXT, MEDIUMTEXT, LONGTEXT -- of various limits; the last is limited to 4GB.
```

For non-character storage (eg, images), there is a similar set of datatypes

```
BINARY(n), VARBINARY(n)
TINYBLOB, BLOB, MEDIUMBLOB, LONGBLOB
```

The various sizes of `TEXT` and `BLOB` indicate whether that is a 1-, 2-, 3-, or 4-byte length field in the implementation.

`NVARCHAR` is a synonym for `VARCHAR`.  Character sets are handled by declaring a column to be, for example, `CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci`.  Such can be defaulted at the database (schema) level, defaulted at the table level, or specified differently for different columns (even in the same table).

Comment: Thanks for your post.But is there a way to implement the row level security (or vpd in oracle virtual private data)?

Comment: Oracle has the kitchen sink.  MySQL/MariaDB is lean and mean.

Comment: The VARCHAR column type has the max size of 65,535 bytes or this size is shared among all columns? (that means that if a column in the same table has size say 1000 bytes the VARCHAR coulum will have a max size of 64535?!)?

Comment: _Each_ `VARCHAR` can be a full 65535.  (I would simply use `TEXT` or `MEDIUMTEXT` if I needed a big varchar.)  There are limitations on how big a _row_ can be.  But there are pretty complex and depend on Engine and Row_format.  You would _probably_ hit some limit if you had 100 columns of `VARCHAR(65535)`